# Comparing the data

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare a set of integers (say alpha) with the result i am getting (say result) 
if result is in alpha i should be able to get the output as mentioned in example below
alpha = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
result = 0,5,6

Final answer should be ABBBBAAB
and what i am getting is ABBBBBBB BBBBBABB BBBBBBAB

As per code

```
public static int[] alpha = new int[8]
    {
        0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
    };
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
                    // Lines of code
                    foreach (var jagged in manager.JaggedList)
                    {  
                      // Lines of code                      
                      foreach (var item in Items)
                      {
                        Console.Write(item.Number); //For Ex output here is (0,5,6)
                        List<int> result = new List<int>();
                        result.Add(item.Number);

                        foreach (var Var in result)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++)
                            {
                                if (result.Contains(alpha[i]))
                                {
                                    Console.Write(alpha[A]);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.Write(alpha[B]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                      }        
    }
```

Final answer should be ABBBBAAB
and what i am getting is ABBBBBBB BBBBBABB BBBBBBAB

Comment: Instead of three innermost loops you should have only two (not nested). One fills `result` (which, btw, should be declared outside the loop), and another one which iterates over `alpha` and checks that result contains it (btw, you can use foreach loop here too).

Answer (score 0):

If `Linq` is  acceptable then just use

```
alpha
  .Select(a => result.Contains(a) ? "A" : "B")
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(x => Console.Write(x));
```

using `foreach` loops

```
foreach(var a in alpha) {
  var found = false;
  foreach(var r in result) {
    if(a == r) {
      found = true;
    }
  }
  Console.Write(found ? "A" : "B");
}
```

Comment: or select to the chars 'A' and 'B' then string join it.

Comment: @user2321864 - Appreciate you taking your time to answer that. However, i am still getting 3 answers instead of 1 incorporating all 3(as mentioned in original question).